# Scan windows file system for directories containing certain words

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, filesystems, directory

Is there a command that I can run on a windows Server 2008 r2 that will only show directories that contain a certain word.

For Example I want to find all directories that contain "logs"

That means it will return these all locations, since they contain the word "Logs"

```
C:\Logs
C:\stuff\ServerLogs
C:\example\Logsforapps
```

Comment: Your third result "C:\example\Logforapps" does not contain "logs".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `cmd` you can do a: `dir /a:d /b /s C:\*logs*`

Or if you've a recent-ish PowerShell version

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path C: -Recurse -Filter *logs* | Select-Object FullName
```

Answer (score 3):

Powershell can deliver what you're after with the following:

```
gci -r c:\temp | where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.name -match "logs"} | foreach { $_.fullname }
```

Comment: +1 And may I suggest you try my answer using `dir`, it very much will provide the full path as a side effect of `/b /s`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Been so long for batch, though /s was only subdirs, forgot it changed the output format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the File Classification Infrastructure (FCI) tool built in to server 2008+ to query the servers in question for the files with the specific word.

Comment: By default File Service manager is not installed. OP asked for a script to run on 500 servers. This wouldn't be a good approach unless all 500 servers had File Services Manager installed. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff627828(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I believe FCI is only required on one server, but I'll verify

Answer (score 0):

How to find directories with 'log' in them.

1. Open File Explorer
2. From the Search upper right corner type **keyword filetype:directory**

Example: log filetype:directory will return all directories with the word log in it. 
Remember to select the starting folder. 
Example: Documents search will return only what was found in the default documents folder. 
C:\Windows will return everything within the Windows folder. 
Selecting C:\ drive with Admin privileges should get you everything on the C: drive.
If you have multiple drives select "Computer" then search keyword filetype:directory

Updated with simple script.

```
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run ("explorer /root,""search-ms:query=logs&crumb=kind:=folder&crumb=location:&""") 
    Set objShell = Nothing
```

The above will search all your internal and mapped drives in your explorer.exe view. 
The location: can be set if you need to check only select drives. 
It would look like

```
    location:C:\
```

You can repeat this for every target drive or folder path you need to search.

```
    &crumb=location:C:\&crumb=location:F:\directory&crumb=location:G:\
```

From my testing on 2008 R2 I found simply leaving the location without a target will search all physical and mapped drives.

```
    &crumb=location:
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with powershell or command line, I have to do this on 500 servers?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about scripting and 500 servers... That sounds like a full-time job. Coffee break coding might be in order here. Not sure the explorer.exe "search-ms:query=log  kind:=folder " command is what you really need but it's a start.

Comment: Updated with a simple script. I tested the other methods listed but liked the option to open file location using the old classical Explorer search view.

Comment: Down voted? Up voted scripts that just don't seem to work for today's server admin. DOS is nice, it shows files but what good is having a screen filled with lines. The Power Shell scripts didn't work when I tested them. You really need to have a server before you can answer a server question.